# Qiskit Portfolio Optimization Application

Tags: qiskit, programming, optimization, quantum-computing-for-finance

I recently got flung into the world of quantum computing and I'm a beginner at coding. I was assigned to do the Portfolio Optimization tutorial of the Qiskit Finance Tutorials and input real data. Truth be told, I'm clueless. It's my understanding that I have to replace the "TICKER" and "RandomDataProvider" parts of the code in order to generate a real-life portfolio.

```
# Generate expected return and covariance matrix from (random) time-series
stocks = [("TICKER%s" % i) for i in range(num_assets)]
data = RandomDataProvider(tickers=stocks,
                 start=datetime.datetime(2016,1,1),
                 end=datetime.datetime(2016,1,30))
data.run()
mu = data.get_period_return_mean_vector()
sigma = data.get_period_return_covariance_matrix()
```

I've imported Quandl and WikipediaDataProvider. I want to keep the number of assets the same, using Microsoft "MSFT", Disney "DIS", Nike "NKE", and Home Depot "HD" stocks.  How might I apply this financial from Quandl to the tutorial? I've tried this so far:

```
num_assets = 4

# Generate expected return and covariance matrix from (random) time-series
stocks = [("MSFT%s" , "DIS%s" , "NKE%s" , "HD%s" % i) for i in range(num_assets)]
data = WikipediaDataProvider(tickers=stocks,
                 token="xeesvko2fu6Bt9jg-B1T",
                 start=datetime.datetime(2016,1,1),
                 end=datetime.datetime(2016,1,30))
data.run()
mu = data.get_period_return_mean_vector()
sigma = data.get_period_return_covariance_matrix()
```

But get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-19e4d9cde1e3> in <module>
      3 # Generate expected return and covariance matrix from (random) time-series
      4 stocks = [("MSFT%s" , "DIS%s" , "NKE%s" , "HD%s" % i) for i in range(num_assets)]
----> 5 data = WikipediaDataProvider(tickers=stocks,
      6                  token="xeesvko2fu6Bt9jg-B1T",
      7                  start=datetime.datetime(2016,1,1),

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class WikipediaDataProvider with abstract methods run
```

I apologize for my limited coding skills - I'm very new to all of this! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the community @Lana! Could you also link the QISKit tutorial you're referencing? At first glance, this seems to be more of a Quandl/Wikipedia problem than Qiskit question

Comment: Thank you @C.Kang! I used the link https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/finance/1_portfolio_optimization.html which was generated from https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/finance/1_portfolio_optimization.ipynb .

Comment: Could you update the links? Those are broken

Comment: I actually got it all amended. Thank you for your willingness to help! :)

Comment: Great! Could you also post your solution? A2As help for future people with similar questions :D

Comment: What part of the code is quantum because I don't see anything different than classical portfolio optimization

Answer (score 3):

I changed the stock parameter to a list of strings and added the line `stockmarket = StockMarket.NASDAQ` as such:

````
num_assets = 4

# Generate expected return and covariance matrix from (random) time-series
stocks = ['MSFT', 'DIS', 'NKE', 'HD']
data = WikipediaDataProvider(
                             token="xeesvko2fu6Bt9jg-B1T",
                             tickers = stocks,
                             stockmarket = StockMarket.NASDAQ,
                             start=datetime.datetime(2016,1,1),
                             end=datetime.datetime(2016,1,30))
data.run()
mu = data.get_period_return_mean_vector()
sigma = data.get_period_return_covariance_matrix()
print(mu)
print(sigma)```
````